# surprising behavior of trigonometric functions in webgl fragment shader

Tags: glsl, webgl

In the following shader, `m1` and `m2` should have the same value because [cos(asin(x)) == sqrt(1.0 - x*x)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Relationships_between_trigonometric_functions_and_inverse_trigonometric_functions).

However, the field produced using `m1` [shows a black ring in the lower left corner](http://thebookofshaders.com/edit.php?log=160815141625) whereas `m2` produces the expected smooth field:

```
precision highp float;

void main() {
    float scale = 10000.0;
    float p = length(gl_FragCoord.xy / scale);

    float m1 = cos(asin(p));
    float m2 = sqrt(1.0 - p*p);

    float v = asin(m1);  // change to m2 to see correct behavior

    float c = degrees(v) / 90.0;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(c), 1.0);
}
```

This behavior is really puzzling. What explains the black ring? I thought it may be a precision issue, but `highp` produces the same result. Or perhaps the black ring represents NaN results, but NaNs shouldn't occur there.

[image: black ring rendering]

This replicates on MacOS 10.10.5 in Chrome/FF. Does not replicate on Windows 10 or iOS 9.3.3. Would something like this be a driver issue?

(For the curious, these formulas calculate latitude for an orthographic projection centered on the north pole.)

--UPDATE--

Confirmed today that MacOS 10.11.6 does *not* show the rendering error. This really seems like a driver/OS issue.

Answer (score 1):

According [to the spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.0.17.pdf)

> asin(x) :  Results are undefined if ∣x∣ > 1.

and

> sqrt(x) :  Results are undefined if x < 0.

Do either of those point out the issue?

Try

```
float m1 = cos(asin(clamp(p, -1., 1.)));
float m2 = sqrt(abs(1.0 - p*p));
```

Comment: `m2` renders correctly, so I will focus on `m1`. Even with the clamp, the rendering is incorrect.

Comment: does your GPU pass these tests? [test1](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/sdk/tests/conformance/glsl/functions/glsl-function-asin.html?webglVersion=1&quiet=0), [test2](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/sdk/tests/conformance/ogles/GL/asin/asin_001_to_006.html?webglVersion=1&quiet=0). Also what is your GPU? Post your GPU/Driver info `about:gpu` contents.

Comment: Chipset Model: Intel HD Graphics 3000
  Type: GPU
  Bus: Built-In
  VRAM (Dynamic, Max): 384 MB
  Vendor: Intel (0x8086)
  Device ID: 0x0116
  Revision ID: 0x0009

Comment: Above is spec from my macbook air. However, I also replicated this on a macbook pro having different hardware, running Mac OS X 10.10.5. Same macbook pro after upgrading to 10.11.6: rendering fixed.

Comment: So basically we've determined it was a driver bug? Your pro wasn't working but now does? Your air still doesn't work (is it on 10.11.6?)

Comment: Yup, I think so. Pro wasn't working on 10.10.5. Now it does, after upgrading to 10.11.6. Air also doesn't work on 10.10.5. Haven't upgraded it yet.