# why do sin/cos return values > 1 in glsl

Tags: glsl, shader

I've got the following shader code in shadertoy:

```c
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    // Normalized pixel coordinates (from 0 to 1)
    vec2 uv = fragCoord/iResolution.xy;

    
    vec3 col = vec3(0.);
    col.r = cos(uv.x* 0.05) > 1. ? 1. : 0.;
    col.g = sin(uv.y*0.05 - 1.5707963267948966) < -1. ? 1. : 0.;

    // Output to screen
    fragColor = vec4(col,1.0);
}
```

I would expect that cos and sin should never return values above 1 (or below -1), and thus I should have an entirely black screen. What am actually seeing is a small band of red and a small band of green. Can anyone explain to me why?

I should also note that I'm on a Mac, and reproduce this in Chrome and FireFox. I do not reproduce this on my ipad or iphone.

shader toy link: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/mdfBDl

[image: screenshot from shadertoy]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: edited to add screenshot

Comment: They probably use an approximation that becomes less accurate away from zero? Try `mod(angle, 2*pi)`.

Comment: uv is already be in the range of 0 to 1, so mod'ing it won't change anything

Comment: What are the actual values it gives outside the expected range? (I just hope that 1. really is the expected value of 1.)

Comment: You could simplify this question by identifying the values for which sin and cos return values greater than 1.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38957186/surprising-behavior-of-trigonometric-functions-in-webgl-fragment-shader

Comment: @Gabriel For posterity (future people seeing this question), it may be interesting to edit the question title and/or body with the exact hardware on which you encounter this problem since this indeed seems like a hardware issue (as suggested by Sniggerfardimungus' answer).

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a shadertoy issue. It's your hardware. I have an NVIDIA 3080 and see an all black screen with your code, but whatever hardware you're using has a very slight approximation error in how it is computing trig functions. It's not unusual.

If you do `col.g = sin(uv.y*0.05 - 1.5707963267948966) < -1.000001 ? 1. : 0.`, I assume you get all black? How many zeroes does it require to go all-black? I'd wager it's very close to machine epsilon for your hardware.

Comment: Everything I see points to this as well. I pulled it up on a linux machine and also see all black. That said, it seems surprising to me that apple hardware would have a bug that allows values > 1 (even by some tiny epsilon).

Comment: Adding 0.0001 does get it all black to me

Comment: It's not a bug, really. Trig functions are implemented in hardware in ways that would make most engineers' heads spin. The number of sacrifices and trade-offs that had to be made to make them fast is - astonishing. Frankly, it's amazing that they're as fast as they are and only inaccurate in the last bit. You could probably get any piece of GPU hardware to return bogus values if you played with them enough.